# $\mathbb C\cup\{\infty\}$ is compact, a "direct proof".

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, compactness

Consider the Riemann sphere $\mathbb C\cup\{\infty\}$ equipped with the usual topology. In most textbooks the compactness of $\mathbb C\cup\{\infty\}$ is proven by showing an explicit homeomorphism with the unit sphere $S^2\subseteq \mathbb R^3$. Is there a direct way to show the compactness? I'd like an argument involving the open coverings of $\mathbb C\cup\{\infty\}$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By definition of the topology, a set $U$ containing $\infty$ is open if and only if $\mathbb{C}\setminus U$ is compact. Each open cover contains one element (at least) that contains $\infty$, so there's a compact set left for the rest to cover.

Comment: In terms of sequences, all sequences will now have a convergent subsequence: those which are bounded are already safe, those who are unbounded have a subsequence that converge to $\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can note/show that the complement of an open neighborhood of $\infty$ is a compact subset of $\Bbb C$. Thus, given any open cover $\mathcal U$ of the Riemann sphere, one of the elements of $\mathcal U$ will have a compact complement, which can then be covered by finitely-many other elements of $\mathcal U$.

Comment: Consider an open covering $\mathcal U$ of the Riemann sphere. If  $V\in\mathcal U$ is  a neighborhood of $\infty$, then $\mathcal U\setminus\{V\}$ is not a covering of $(\mathbb C\cup\{\infty\})\setminus V$. In general the union of the elements of $\mathcal U\setminus\{V\}$ is bigger than $(\mathbb C\cup\{\infty\})\setminus V$.

Comment: Ah ok, the notion of "open cover" for a subspace of a given topological space is different!

Comment: @Galoisfan: Exactly. When we say that $(\Bbb C\cup\{\infty\})\setminus V$ can be covered by $\mathcal U\setminus\{V\},$ we mean that $$(\Bbb C\cup\{\infty\})\setminus V\subseteq\bigcup\mathcal U\setminus\{V\}.$$ In fact, we can do the same thing for the whole space. A collection of open subsets of a space $X$ is an open cover of $X$ (in the sense that you're used to) iff $$X\subseteq\bigcup\mathcal U.$$ The reverse inclusion holds trivially in that case, and this definition is more readily generalized to proper subsets of the space.